# How to input a string in IRuby + Jupyter?

Tags: sciruby, iruby

I'm using iruby on Jupyter.  In python kernel (ipython), one can input a string from notebook by calling `input()` function.

Is it possible to achieve the same thing in iruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Jupyter Notebook, 
try
`IRuby.input`

https://github.com/SciRuby/iruby/tree/master/lib/iruby/input

But this input box may not work in Jupyter Lab.

Answer (score 2):

Simple text input is done with `IRuby.input`:

```
name = IRuby.input 'Enter your name'
```

Multiple fields of input is done with `IRuby.form`:

```
result = IRuby.form do 
  input :username
  button
end
```

It returns a Hash with the input field names as labels.